# How a control can move to the position of another control and be same size with translate transform and scale transform?

Tags: wpf

I have two controls in grid. I want to make a animation to move a control to the position of another control and with the same size of of another control.
Here is part of code:

```
<Grid x:Name="OutGrid" Width="1280" Height="720" Background="Red">
        <Image x:Name="Img_2" Width="480" Source="Images/0_0012_2.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Image x:Name="Img_1" Width="240" Source="Images/0_0012_2.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                    <ScaleTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use scale? Changing the width and height may give you better results.

Comment: Additionally, animations with dynamic values need to be applied from code, not xaml.

Comment: Yes, I need to make a animation. can I use width or height to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate Grid from one position to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459289/animate-grid-from-one-position-to-another)

Comment: I've got it. Do it with thickness and scaletransform can figure it out. But thickness value need some fix. Thank you very much!